# $emit an event from child to parent in vue.js, es6 syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I'm pretty new to Vue.js, and I use ES6 syntax with `vue-class-component`. I'm having a problem while trying to emit an event from a child to its parent.

I followed the logic of the default Vue.js syntax but can't seem to have my parent catch an event emitted by the the child. Code:

**Child Component**

I attached a click event listener on every `<li>`, which calls a function that emits an event. The event listener is defined on the parent.

```js
 export default class HorizontalNavigation {

  handleClick (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(e.target.dataset.section);
    this.$emit('ChangeView', e.target.dataset.section);
  }

  render (h) {
    return (
      <div class={ style.horizontalNavigation } >
        <div class='sections-wrapper'>
          <div class={ style.sections }>
            <ol>
              <li><a on-click={ this.handleClick } href='#1' data-section='1' class='selected'>We are</a></li>
              <li><a on-click={ this.handleClick } href='#2' data-section='2'>Services</a></li>
              <li><a on-click={ this.handleClick } href='#3' data-section='3'>Cases</a></li>
              <li><a on-click={ this.handleClick } href='#4' data-section='4'>Studio</a></li>
              <li><a on-click={ this.handleClick } href='#5' data-section='5'>Career</a></li>
              <li><a on-click={ this.handleClick } href='#6' data-section='6'>Contact</a></li>
            </ol>

            <span class='filling-line' aria-hidden='true'></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Parent Component**

```js
export default class ViewsContainer {

  ChangeView (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }

  render (h) {
      return (
        <div class={ style.restrictOverflow } >
          <HorizontalNavigation />
          <main class={ style.viewsContainer } on-ChangeView={ this.ChangeView     } >
            <SingleView dataSection='weare' id='1' class='selected' />
            <SingleView dataSection='services' id='2' />
            <SingleView dataSection='cases' id='3' />
            <SingleView dataSection='studio' id='4' />
            <SingleView dataSection='career' id='5' />
            <SingleView dataSection='contact' id='6' />
          </main>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Following the vue.js syntax, I should be able to listen to the child's event from the parent, by emitting the event from the element, but the parent doesn't seem to catch the event.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to `$emit` on the view model you want to receive your `$emit`, use a `bus` or use https://vuex.vuejs.org/.

## Emitting to parent directly

The easiest way, is to simply `$emit` from the child directly to the parent component:

```js
this.$parent.$emit('ChangeView', e.target.dataset.section);
```

This is *OK*, but if you have a long chain of components you need to `$emit` to each `$parent` in the chain.

## Emiting via an Event Bus

You can use Vue to create a global event bus very simply. You create an instance of Vue in your main component, then all other components in your application can `emit` events to it, and use `on` to react to those events.

```js
var bus = new Vue({});
var vm = new Vue({
  methods: {
    changeView() {
      bus.$emit('ChangeView', e.target.dataset.section);
    }
  });
```

It is also possible to emit to `$root` but this isn't recommended. However, if your `app` does get quite complex you may want to consider using Vues own state management system, [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), instead.

## Listening for events

You can listen for the `$emit` in the viewmodel using `$on` and listening for the specific event:

```js
    var vm = new Vue({
      created() {
         this.$on('ChangeView', section => {
            console.log(section);
          });
      }
    );
```

This would also be similar is you were using the bus, but you would just reference the bus instead:

```js
bus.$on('ChangeView', ...);
```

And you may also use it directly in your html using `v-on`:

```html
<div v-on:ChangeView="doSomething"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Craig ! But how do you listen to it on the parent, I can't get anything coming through...

Comment: Thank you very much Craig ! I also did a mistake by putting on-ChangeView listener on the parent and not on the instance itself. So what solved my problem was to do : 
<HorizontalNavigation on-ChangeView={ this.ChangeView } /> in ViewsContainer.

Thanks again for your time !

Comment: What is `ChangeView` here ?

Comment: This is a life savior. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 17):

In **[Vue](https://vuejs.org/)**, you can communicate from children up to parent components by **emitting events**. The **child compoment** *"emits"* an event with **[`$emit`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#ad)**  & the **parent component** *"listens"* for it like so:

**Child Component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="this.handleClick">Click me!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "BaseButton",
  methods: {
    handleClick: function() {
      this.$emit("clickFromChildComponent");
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**Parent Component:**

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <h1>Passing a event from child up to parent!</h1>
    <BaseButton @clickFromChildComponent="handleClickInParent"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BaseButton from "./BaseButton";

export default {
  components: {
    BaseButton
  },
  name: "Home",
  methods: {
    handleClickInParent: function() {
      alert('Event accessed from parent!');
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**You can find a *working sample code implementation*** **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/emitting-event-from-child-to-parent-component-vuejs-rq5qs)** & use it in your own context.

Answer (score 8):

Unless I'm missing something (very likely), in a simple example like this, you just need to listen for the `emit`ted event in your component. For example, in your parent element, you would have:

```js
<HorizontalNavigation v-on:ChangeView={this.ChangeView} />
```

Then in your child (`HorizontalNavigation`) component, you would `emit` the 'ChangeView' event:

```js
this.$emit('ChangeView', e.target.dataset.section);
```

I tried this in similar code myself, based on a comment you made on @craig_h's answer, and it was what I needed. I didn't need to `emit` to parent, or use a bus, or vuex.

Comment: Curly brace create problem in my code . <HorizontalNavigation v-on:ChangeView=this.ChangeView />  without curly braces and implementing ChangeView in method of the component works for me .

Answer (score 2):

*If you end up here looking for Vue 3 script setup*

It's good practice for readibility to declare emits with [defineEmits](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-and-defineemits) and then use the returned function for emitting

**Child component :**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="handleClick">Increment</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const emit = defineEmits(['custom'])

const handleClick = () => {
  emit('custom')
}
</script>
```

**Parent component :**

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ counter }}</h1>
  <Button @custom="handleCustom"/>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Button from './components/Button.vue'

const counter = ref(0)

const handleCustom = () => {
  counter.value++
}
</script>
```

[Here is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/emit-an-event-from-child-to-parent-in-vuejs-es6-syntax?file=src/App.vue) the working implementation